# Cannot specify no_proxy for Capybara with poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I there, I am a bit stuck with this...

#### I can't find documentation on how to tell *Capybara/Poltergeist with phantomjs* to avoid the proxy and go directly to the specified IP.

Host machine (Fedora 20) config? Already tried setting no_proxy

Or, Application config?

A bit of context:

I am making a few web tests using Capybara with Poltergeist/PhantomJS. Unfortunately, my company decided that any request for an internal network that hits the proxy won't be forwarded anymore. So, since I am testing between two different machines in the company's intranet, putting the env variable no_proxy should be enough. But no...

Answer (score 0):

Well... after digging a bit more on the PhantomJS github [API Reference](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference) page I found the answer.
There is an option `--proxy-type=[http|socks5|none]` that can be passed to phantomjs command line or in the initialization of Capybara with poltergeist like this:

```
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_wait_time = 60
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, { :phantomjs_options => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--proxy-type=none'] })
end
```